# Magento site in shows 404 error on frontend, backend, all place

Tags: magento

`myProject/var/log/system.log` shows

```
2015-04-19T06:39:20+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\featherfox\app\etc\modules\Oye_License.xml): failed to open stream: Permission denied  in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\lib\Varien\Simplexml\Config.php on line 496
```

And i get `404 error: Page not found.` on all places.

Comment: Give permission to write to that folder

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a permissions issue. Normally magento needs the following permissions.

- Files should be 644,
- Folders should be 755,
- Mage executable should be 550 permissions,